# Special characters not returned correctly

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, localization, internationalization

I have the following German phrase in a view of my .Net MVC application:

```
auf der Straße
```

but when I look at the source that is returned

```
 auf der StraÃŸe
```

I can see that it doesn't match what is in the view.  I have set the Thread's UI culture to 'de-DE' and the CurrentUICulture to 'de-DE'

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("de-DE");
```

In my web.config file, I've set the request and response encoding to utf-8:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />
```

Anything else I can check to figure out how to return the text that is in the view and not something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, you need the fileEncoding set to UTF-8 as well, otherwise the text that is sent from the server is not correct.

```
<globalization requestEncoding="UTF-8" responseEncoding="UTF-8" fileEncoding="UTF-8" />
```